# Using Selenium to run Javascipt and return the results

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to use Python Selenium to grab the data payload populating this [page](https://www.route.org.uk/q42022-dashboard). Data seems to being fed in using Javascript from some Tableau API's. I'm not really a Javascript guy, but I've had a look in Chrometools and have found the following .js files listed as resources:

https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/jquery.min.js
https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/ViewerBootstrap.js
https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/jquery.min.js
https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/mscorlib.min.js
https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/jsstrings_en.js
https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/messages.en_US.js
https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/formatters-and-parsers.en_US.js
https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/vqlweb.js
https://public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/require.min.js

I have tried the below code with a few of the different .js files and all I keep getting back is None.

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
sys.path.append("G:\\Python36\\mypath")
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()


chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
#d['goog:loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' }
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

drv = driver.get("https://www.route.org.uk/q42022-dashboard")

print(driver.execute_script("return //public.tableau.com/vizql/v_202242301300809/javascripts/ViewerBootstrap.js"))
driver.quit()
```

...at this stage I don't know exactly what I should be getting back in terms of a result, but something that resembles the content of the rendered page would be a good start...

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Payload is what you send the server, you want the response I think. If you go to network panel of dev tools and select xhr/fetch you can search on the left side for the data you're looking for and it will show you which response it was in.

In this case it was here for me: https://public.tableau.com/vizql/w/RouteQ42020Impactmapping/v/RouteQ42022ImpactMapping/bootstrapSession/sessions/175164D327D745279A626B89EE24F1B1-0:0 (this was a post xhr which you don't see a lot of anymore)

I understand that selenium-wire can capture those responses but I haven't used it.